# Proving $S_1-S_2$ is non-positive

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have system number (1) as:

$S_1’=-bS_1I_1+(1-c)aI_1$

$I_1’=bS_1I_1-aI_1$

And on the other hand I have system number (2) as:

$S_2’=-bS_2I_2+aI_2$

$I_2’=bS_2I_2-aI_2$

All parameters $a,b,c>0$.

Both systems have the same initial conditions as in $S_1(0)=S_2(0)=s_0>0$ and $I_1(0)=I_2(0)=i_0>0$.

I want to prove that $S_1-S_2$ is non-positive.
What I did so far:

1. I found $S_2$ explicitly though not sure it is useful as $S_1$ can’t be found explicitly unfortunately.
2. Using the initial conditions then I have $S_1=  \frac{(1-c)a}{b}+(s_0- \frac{(1-c)a}{b}$$ )e^{-\int_{0}^{t} bI_1(t) \ dt}$.
3. Similarly, I obtained $S_2=  \frac{a}{b}+(s_0- \frac{a}{b}$$ )e^{-\int_{0}^{t} bI_2(t) \ dt}$.
4. So from 2 and 3 it is deduced that $(S_1-S_2)(0)=0$ and $$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}(S_1-S_2)(t)=-ca/b.$$
5. By manipulating the equation for $S_1$ then we have the relationship $e^{-\int_{0}^{t} bI_1(t) \ dt}= \frac{|bS_1(t)-(1-c)a|}{|bs_0-(1-c)a|} $

Despite all that I can’t seem to prove that $(S_1-S_2)(t)$ is negative for $t>0$. I checked this via simulations and indeed it is the case but I’m trying by contradiction and can’t find something that can lead to a contradiction in anything. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to the widespread belief, your system (which looks like an "endemic" version of SIR with acquired immunity, so I naturally wonder whether that is what it really models) can be solved explicitly in the sense that the 3D trajectory $(t,S,I)$ has a parametric representation in terms of two elementary functions and one integral of an elementary function, which allows one to analyze it if not in full, then, at least, to the extent sufficient for answering questions like yours. I'll set $b=1$ (just by scaling time) for convenience.

Replacing $S$ by $S-a$, we see that we need to consider the family of equations
$$
\dot S_\sigma=-I_\sigma(S_\sigma+\sigma),\qquad \dot I_\sigma=S_\sigma I_\sigma
$$
with initial data $S_\sigma(0)=s\in\mathbb R$, $I_\sigma(0)=i>0$ (note that after subtracting $a$ we no longer can assume that $s>0$) and to show that $S_\sigma\le S_0$ for all times if $\sigma>0$.

Clearly, $I_\sigma>0$ for all times and, thereby, $S_\sigma$ goes towards $-\sigma$ in a monotone fashion as $t\to+\infty$ (however, it doesn't need to reach it at $+\infty$, so your analysis of the limit there is flawed as written). So, if $-\sigma\le s\le 0$, $S_0$ goes up, $S_\sigma$ goes down, and the inequality is trivial. Thus we can assume WLOG that $s$ and $s+\sigma$ have the same sign.

Now, given the solution $S_\sigma(t), I_\sigma(t)$,  solve the equation
$$
\frac{dt_{\sigma}}{d\xi}=I_\sigma(t_\sigma(\xi))^{-1}
$$
with the initial condition $t_\sigma(0)=0$.

Note that $S_\sigma+I_\sigma$ is non-increasing for $\sigma>0$ and $S_\sigma$ stays bounded between $s$ and $-\sigma$, so $I_\sigma$ stays bounded as well. Thus the values of $t_\sigma$ cover $[0,+\infty)$ (though $+\infty$ can be reached with finite $\xi$) and, therefore, $t_\sigma$ is a decent time change. Switching to that new variable (i.e., considering $t_\sigma, S_\sigma\circ t_\sigma, I_\sigma\circ t_\sigma$, we get the system
$$
\frac{d}{d\xi} S_\sigma=-(S_\sigma+\sigma)\qquad \frac{d}{d\xi}I_\sigma=S_\sigma,
\qquad \frac{d}{d\xi}t_\sigma=I_\sigma^{-1}\,,
$$
which, taking into account the initial conditions,  readily solves as
$$
S_\sigma(\xi)=-\sigma+(s+\sigma)e^{-\xi},
\\
I_\sigma(\xi)=i-\sigma\xi+(s+\sigma)(1-e^{-\xi}),
\\
t_\sigma(\xi)=\int_0^\xi\frac{d\eta}{i-\sigma\eta+(s+\sigma)(1-e^{-\eta})}\,,
$$
where the meaningful values of $\xi$ are those for which $I_\sigma>0$ on $[0,\xi]$.

Due to the simultaneous monotonicity of $S_0$ and $S_\sigma$, the inequality we want to prove is equivalent to the statement that if $S_\sigma(\xi_\sigma)=S_0(\xi_0)$, then $t_\sigma(\xi_\sigma)\le t_0(\xi_0)$ if $s,s+\sigma>0$ and $t_\sigma(\xi_\sigma)\ge t_0(\xi_0)$ if $s,s+\sigma<0$.

To prove this statement, let us define $\lambda=\lambda(\eta)\ge 0$ by
$$
S_\sigma(\lambda)=-\sigma+(s+\sigma)e^{-\lambda}=se^{-\eta}=S_0(\eta)
$$
as long as $S_0(\eta)$ makes sense and the equation is solvable.

We derive from this definition
$$
e^{\lambda-\eta}=-\frac{\sigma}se^{\lambda}+\frac{s+\sigma}{s}
\\
d\lambda=\frac{s}{s+\sigma}e^{\lambda-\eta}\,d\eta=\left[-\frac{\sigma}{s+\sigma}e^{\lambda}+1\right]\,d\eta
\\
(s+\sigma)(1-e^{-\lambda})=s(1-e^{-\eta})\,.
$$

Using all these identities together with $\xi_\sigma=\lambda(\xi_0)$ and making the change of variable $\eta\mapsto\lambda(\eta)$ in the integral defining $t_\sigma(\xi_\sigma)$, we see that we have to compare
$$
t_\sigma(\xi_\sigma)=\int_0^{\xi_0}\frac
{\left[-\frac{\sigma}{s+\sigma}e^{\lambda}+1\right]\,d\eta}
{i-\sigma\lambda+s(1-e^{-\eta})}
$$
and
$$
t_0(\xi_0)=\int_0^{\xi_0}\frac{d\eta}{i+s(1-e^{-\eta})}\,.
$$
We shall just compare the integrands. Multiplying by the denominators (which should stay non-negative throughout $[0,\xi_0]$ for the assumption $S_\sigma(t_\sigma)=S_0(t_0)$ to be possible) and cancelling equal terms we get to compare
$$
-\frac{\sigma}{s+\sigma}e^{\lambda}(i+s(1-e^{-\eta})\text{ and }-\sigma\lambda
$$
on $[0,\xi_0]$.

Case 1: $s,s+\sigma<0$ (increasing). Then $LHS\ge 0\ge RHS$.

Case 2: $s,s+\sigma>0$ (decreasing). Then (since $i>0$),
$$
LHS\le -\frac{\sigma}{s+\sigma}e^{\lambda}s(1-e^{-\eta})=
-\sigma e^{\lambda}(1-e^{-\lambda})
\\
=-\sigma(e^\lambda-1)\le -\sigma\lambda=RHS
$$
and we are done.

*Edit*

After a discussion with Brenda, we came to the conclusion that this technique allows one to prove a bit more, namely that $S_{\sigma}(t)$ is a decreasing function of $\sigma$ for fixed $t>0$.

To achieve that, it will be convenient to switch to the level difference $a$ as the independent variable, i.e., to put
$$
S_\sigma(\eta)=s-a
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
(s+\sigma)(1-e^{-\eta})=a.
$$
Then, rewriting everything in terms of $a$, we shall have
$$
t_\sigma(A)=\int_0^A\frac{da}{(s+\sigma-a)[i+\sigma\log(1-\frac a{s+\sigma})+a]}
$$
and the desired monotonicity will follow from the following

*Claim*:
If $s+\sigma\ne 0$, then
$$
\frac d{d\sigma}\left\{(s+\sigma-a)[i+\sigma\log(1-\tfrac a{s+\sigma})+a]\right\}>0
$$
*as long as* the expression in brackets ($I_\sigma(a)$) is positive.

*Proof of the claim*:

Honestly computing the derivative, we see that we need to prove that
$$
[i+\sigma\log(1-\tfrac a{s+\sigma})+a]\\
+(s+\sigma-a)\log(1-\tfrac a{s+\sigma})+\frac{a\sigma}{s+\sigma}>0\,.
$$
If $s+\sigma<0$, then all three terms are non-negative (note that $\frac{a}{s+\sigma}\in(0,1)$ regardless of the sign of $s+\sigma$).

Now assume that $s+\sigma>0$. Then, dividing by $s+\sigma$ and denoting $y=\frac a{s+\sigma}\in(0,1)$, $z=\frac \sigma{s+\sigma}>0$, we get the inequality
$$
[\tfrac{i}{s+\sigma}+z\log(1-y)+y]+(1-y)\log(1-y)+yz> 0
$$
to prove under the assumption that the expression in brackets is non-negative. Since $i>0$, it reduces to
$$
\max[0,z\log(1-y)+y]+(1-y)\log(1-y)+yz> 0
$$
Now observe that as long as the maximum is positive, the LHS decreases in $z$ and as soon as it hits $0$, it starts to increase in $z$, so the worst $z$ is $z=-\frac{y}{\log(1-y)}$. Plugging this value in, we see that we need to prove that for $y\in(0,1)$, we have
$$
y^2>(1-y)\log^2(1-y)\,.
$$
Returning to the variable $\eta>0$ ($1-y=e^{-\eta}$), we rewrite it as
$$
(1-e^{-\eta})^2> e^{-\eta}\eta^2\,
$$
or
$$
e^{\eta}+e^{-\eta}-2>\eta^2\,
$$
which is immediate from the Taylor series for the exponent, say.

Comment: I already managed to prove that both S_1-S_2 and I_1-I_2 are non-positive by analysing the equations their derivatives satisfy. But your approach is completely different and interesting. But the thing that puzzles me is why can we define the differential equation of time related to 1/I_delta? Why is it “legal” in the first place? Also, based on your solution for S_delta then S_0 is the same but with delta=0 which seems that the difference S_delta-S_0 is always decreasing but there’s a case in my simulations where the difference initially decreases and then increases to its limit.

Comment: No, I haven't claimed anything about the monotonicity of $S_\delta-S_0$ as my approach only gives monotonicity of the difference of *the inverse functions* (time as a function of value), which is not the same at all. It would be interesting to see how you did it as well to compare the arguments. My main point was actually my first sentence: the model is explicitly solvable in a certain sense, so you can easily figure out a lot of things about it by playing with elementary functions and their integrals.

Comment: The differential equation is legal just because *every* differential equation $\dot t=G(t)$ is legal as long as $G$ is, say, Lipschitz, and $1/I_\sigma$ is defined for all positive $t$ and even smooth, so I can use it (after it is there).

Comment: @Brenda Oh, yeah, I should have put your name in front of my comments to let you know that I answered. Doing it now :-) Feel free to ask more questions any time.

Comment: I still don’t get it. According to the solution, if S_delta=-delta+(s+delta)exp(-xi) then S_0=s(*exp(-xi) (because the same tricks can be done with S_0) which means the difference satisfies S_delta-S_0=delta(exp(-xi)-1) and that supposedly is a decreasing function.

Comment: What I did is basically rewrite S_1’-S_2’ as S_1’-S_2’=A(S_1-S_2)+B(t) where B results in a negative function and because (S_1-S_2)(0)=0 then the conclusion is clear.

Comment: @Brenda Those are $S_\delta(t_\delta(\xi))$ and $S_0(t_0(\xi))$ and the clocks $t_\delta$ and $t_0$ are different!!!! (so you don't get the values *at the same point* for the same value of the parameter).
Can you tell me your $A$ and $B$? For some reason I am not seeing them myself :-)

Comment: I guess that the clocks are different so now I can’t understand what is the point of all your work now. The functions S_1 and S_2 do not intersect each other except for t=0, the whole solution is based on completely different times and can’t be used to analyze the behaviour of S_1-S_2. I don’t understand your approach, sorry.

Comment: @Brenda I show the inequality for times needed to reach the same level instead of showing the inequality for levels at the same time. It is like saying that if two cars move in the same direction, then to say that car A is behind the car B at every moment is the same as to say that for every point on the road, A passes it later than B does. That is all. I still cannot reproduce you approach, on the other hand. Can you elaborate? :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142301/discussion-between-brenda-and-fedja).

Comment: why i/(s+sigma)+zlog(1-y)+y is reduced to max[0,zlog(1-y)+y] ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the approach initiated by Fedja for a bit more general case, taking into account the initial conditions, $S_{\sigma_1}$ and $S_{\sigma_2}$ readily solve as
$$
S_{\sigma_i}(\xi)=-\sigma_i+(s+\sigma_i)e^{-\xi},
\\
I_{\sigma_i}(\xi)=i-\sigma_i\xi+(s+\sigma_i)(1-e^{-\xi}),
\\
t_{\sigma_i}(\xi)=\int_0^\xi\frac{d\eta}{i-\sigma_i\eta+(s+\sigma_i)(1-e^{-\eta})}\,,
$$
where the meaningful values of $\xi$ are those for which $I_{\sigma_i}>0$ on $[0,\xi]$.

Due to the simultaneous monotonicity of $S_{\sigma_1}$ and $S_{\sigma_2}$, the inequality we want to prove is equivalent to the statement that if $S_{\sigma_1}(\xi_1)=S_{\sigma_2}(\xi_2)$, then $t_{\sigma_1}(\xi_1)\le t_{\sigma_2}(\xi_2)$ if $s+\sigma_1,s+\sigma_2>0$ and $t_{\sigma_1}(\xi_1)\ge t_{\sigma_2}(\xi_2)$ if $s+{\sigma_1},s+\sigma_2<0$.

To prove this statement, let us define $\lambda=\lambda(\eta)\ge 0$ by
$$
S_{\sigma_1}(\lambda)=-\sigma_1+(s+\sigma_1)e^{-\lambda}=-\sigma_2+(s+\sigma_2)e^{-\eta}=S_{\sigma_2}(\eta)
$$
as long as $S_{\sigma_2}(\eta)$ makes sense and the equation is solvable.

$\color{red}{\text{alternative version below from here}}$

We derive from this definition
$$
e^{\lambda-\eta}=-\frac{(\sigma_1-\sigma_2)}{s+\sigma_2}e^{\lambda}+\frac{s+\sigma_1}{s+\sigma_2}
\\
d\lambda=\frac{s+\sigma_2}{s+\sigma_1}e^{\lambda-\eta}\,d\eta=\left[-\frac{\sigma_1-\sigma_2}{s+\sigma_1}e^{\lambda}+1\right]\,d\eta
\\
(s+\sigma_1)(1-e^{-\lambda})=(s+\sigma_2)(1-e^{-\eta})\,.
$$

Using all these identities together with $\xi_1=\lambda(\xi_2)$ and making the change of variable $\eta\mapsto\lambda(\eta)$ in the integral defining $t_{\sigma_1}(\xi_1)$, we see that we have to compare
$$
t_{\sigma_1}(\xi_1)=\int_0^{\xi_2}\frac
{\left[-\frac{\sigma_1-\sigma_2}{s+\sigma_1}e^{\lambda}+1\right]\,d\eta}
{i-\sigma_1\lambda+(s+\sigma_2)(1-e^{-\eta})}
$$
and
$$
t_{\sigma_2}(\xi_2)=\int_0^{\xi_2}\frac{d\eta}{i-\sigma_2\eta+(s+\sigma_2)(1-e^{-\eta})}\,.
$$
We shall just compare the integrands. Multiplying by the denominators (which should stay non-negative throughout $[0,\xi_2]$ for the assumption $S_{\sigma_1}(t_{\sigma_1})=S_{\sigma_2}(t_{\sigma_2})$ to be possible) and cancelling equal terms we get to compare
$$
-\frac{\sigma_1-\sigma_2}{s+\sigma_1}e^{\lambda}(i-\sigma_2\eta+(s+\sigma_2)(1-e^{-\eta})\text{ and }-\sigma_1\lambda+\sigma_2\eta
$$
on $[0,\xi_2]$.

Case 1: $s+\sigma_1,s+\sigma_2<0$ (increasing). Then $LHS\ge 0\ge RHS$. (Quite easy)

Case 2: $s+\sigma_1,s+\sigma_2>0$ (decreasing). Then (since $i>0$),
$$
LHS\le -\frac{\sigma_1-\sigma_2}{s+\sigma_1}e^{\lambda}(-\sigma_2\eta+(s+\sigma_2)(1-e^{-\eta}))=
-(\sigma_1-\sigma_2) e^{\lambda}(1-e^{-\lambda})+\frac{\sigma_2\eta(\sigma_1-\sigma_2)e^{\lambda}}{s+\sigma_1}
\\
=-(\sigma_1-\sigma_2)(e^\lambda-1) +\frac{\sigma_2\eta(\sigma_1-\sigma_2)e^{\lambda}}{s+\sigma_1}\le -(\sigma_1-\sigma_2)\lambda+\sigma_2\eta
$$
and we are a bit in trouble?

Maybe we can bound the expression $$
-\frac{\sigma_1-\sigma_2}{s+\sigma_1}e^{\lambda}i$$ but not sure how.

$\color{red}{\text{alternative}}$

We derive from this definition
$$
d\lambda=\frac{s+\sigma_2}{s+\sigma_1}e^{\lambda-\eta}\,d\eta
\\
(s+\sigma_1)(1-e^{-\lambda})=(s+\sigma_2)(1-e^{-\eta})\,.
$$

Using all these identities together with $\xi_1=\lambda(\xi_2)$ and making the change of variable $\eta\mapsto\lambda(\eta)$ in the integral defining $t_{\sigma_1}(\xi_1)$, we see that we have to compare
$$
t_{\sigma_1}(\xi_1)=\int_0^{\xi_2}\frac
{\left[\frac{s+\sigma_2}{s+\sigma_1}e^{\lambda-\eta}\right]\,d\eta}
{i-\sigma_1\lambda+(s+\sigma_1)(1-e^{-\lambda})}
$$
and
$$
t_{\sigma_2}(\xi_2)=\int_0^{\xi_2}\frac{d\eta}{i-\sigma_2\eta+(s+\sigma_2)(1-e^{-\eta})}\,.
$$
We shall just compare the integrands. Multiplying by the denominators (which should stay non-negative throughout $[0,\xi_2]$ for the assumption $S_{\sigma_1}(t_{\sigma_1})=S_{\sigma_2}(t_{\sigma_2})$ to be possible) and additionally by $(s+\sigma_1)e^{-\lambda}$, we get to compare
$$
(s+\sigma_1)e^{-\lambda}[i-\sigma_1\lambda+(s+\sigma_1)(1-e^{-\lambda})]
\\
\text{and}
\\
(s+\sigma_2)e^{-\eta}[i-\sigma_2\eta+(s+\sigma_2)(1-e^{-\eta})]
$$
where $\lambda=\lambda(\eta)$ on $[0,\xi_2]$.

Expressing both $\lambda$ and $\eta$ in terms of the common value $a=(s+\sigma_1)(1-e^{-\lambda})=(s+\sigma_2)(1-e^{-\eta})$, we get the following inequality in terms of $a,\sigma_1,\sigma_2$:

$\color{red}{\text{Try to continue yourself from here}}$

Comment: Now what proceeds from here is quite clear :) , again, elegant and efficient approaches.