# Proving $S_1-S_2$ is monotone decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, monotone-functions

I have system number (1) as:

$S_1’=-bS_1I_1+(1-c)aI_1$

$I_1’=bS_1I_1-aI_1$

And on the other hand I have system number (2) as:

$S_2’=-bS_2I_2+aI_2$

$I_2’=bS_2I_2-aI_2$

All parameters $a,b,c>0$.

Both systems have the same initial conditions as in $S_1(0)=S_2(0)=s_0>0$ and $I_1(0)=I_2(0)=i_0>0$.

I want to prove that $S_1-S_2$ is decreasing for $s_0>\frac{a}{b}$.
What I proved so far:

1. I proved $S_1-S_2$ and $I_1-I_2$ are negative for all $t>0$.
2. Using the initial conditions then I have $S_1=  \frac{(1-c)a}{b}+(s_0- \frac{(1-c)a}{b}$$ )e^{-\int_{0}^{t} bI_1(t) \ dt}$.
3. Similarly, I obtained $S_2=  \frac{a}{b}+(s_0- \frac{a}{b}$$ )e^{-\int_{0}^{t} bI_2(t) \ dt}$.
4. From 2 and 3 we conclude that $S_1,S_2$ are monotone decreasing and that for $s_0>\frac{a}{b}$ we have $\frac{-ca}{b}<S_1-S_2<0$.
5. Initially we have $(S_1-S_2)’<0$ and because $S_1,S_2$ are $C^\infty$ then $(S_1-S_2)$ decreases initially and $$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}(S_1-S_2)’(t)=0.$$
6. I expressed $(S_1-S_2)’=F(t)(S_1-S_2)+G(t)$ where $G(t),F(t)$ are negative ($F(t)$ starts being negative from a certain point $t_0$ in case that $F(0)>0$) and descending toward finite limit.

Despite all that I can’t seem to prove that $(S_1-S_2)(t)$ is decreasing for $t>0$. I checked this via simulations and indeed it is the case but I’m trying by contradiction and can’t find something that can lead to a contradiction in anything. Help is appreciated!

Comment: The second system can be solved explicitly by noting that $I_2'=I_2(bS_2-a)=I_2(b(s_0+i_0-I_2)-a)$. This is very close to the logistic differential equation. I do not know whether it can help or not. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#Logistic_differential_equation

Comment: It doesn’t help because the first system cannot be solved explicitly so I doubt it very much. Also the answer given below is based on an assumption I did not write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is false in general. A particular counterexample is $b=1, a=30, c=0.5, s_0=31, i_0=1$ where the monotonicity reverses for $t>0.95$. Below I'll try to explain how I found that and what is behind that effect.

We will change the variables like in [my answer to Brenda's previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4619831/proving-s-1-s-2-is-non-positive?rq=1) and work with the "implicit solution"
$$
S_\sigma(\xi)=-\sigma+(s+\sigma)e^{-\xi},
\\
I_\sigma(\xi)=i-\sigma\xi+(s+\sigma)(1-e^{-\xi}),
\\
t_\sigma(\xi)=\int_0^\xi\frac{d\eta}{i-\sigma\eta+(s+\sigma)(1-e^{-\eta})}\,,
$$
where the meaningful values of $\xi$ are those for which $I_\sigma>0$ on $[0,\xi]$.

The current conjecture is equivalent to the statement that for $s,\sigma>0$, we have
$$
-\frac{dS_{\sigma}}{dt_{\sigma}}\ge -\frac{dS_0}{dt_0}
$$
when $t_{\sigma}=t_0$.

The last condition (the agreement of time) is equivalent to the differential relation between the parameters $\xi_\sigma$ and $\xi_0$, which is
$$
\frac{d\xi_\sigma}{i-\sigma\xi_\sigma+(s+\sigma)(1-e^{-\xi_\sigma})}=
\frac{d\xi_0}{i+s(1-e^{-\xi_0})},.
$$
Introducing new variables $y=1-e^{-\xi_\sigma}$ and $x=1-e^{-\xi_0}$ and playing with the chain rule and elementary algebra a bit more, we arrive at the following equivalent reformulation of the conjecture:

If $y(0)=0$ and $y'=F(x,y)=\frac{i+\sigma\log(1-y)+(s+\sigma)y}{i+sx}\frac{1-y}{1-x}$ on $[0,1)$, then $\frac{s+\sigma}s y'=\frac{s+\sigma}sF(x,y)\ge 1$ on $[0,1)$.

Since $\psi(x)=-\log(1-y)-y\ge 0$, it is easy to see that $y$ lags behind $x$ all the time and as $x\to 1$, we have $y\to y_1$ where $y_1$ solves the equation $i+sy_1-\sigma\psi(y_1)=0$. Clearly, $y_1<1$.

We now will consider the "endgame" for $x$ close to $1$. Then $F(x,y)\approx \frac{(\sigma\psi'(y_1)-s)(1-y_1)}{i+s} \frac{y_1-y}{1-x}$. If the first fraction equals $\rho>1$, then in the endgame we have, roughly speaking, $y_1-y\approx (1-x)^\rho$ and $F(x,y)\to 0$ as $x\to 1$. It is fairly clear that we can achieve it by increasing $\sigma>0$ to some large value keeping other parameters fixed because $\psi'(y)/\psi(y)\to+\infty$ as $y\to 0$ and that what the above example (in which $s=i=1, \sigma=15$, so $y_1\approx 0.3686$ and $\rho\approx 2.45$) is based upon.

I do not know whether $\rho>1$ is a necessary condition for breaking the monotonicity though.

Comment: I don’t understand anything you did in the last paragraph. Does this try to imply that we can’t have t_delta=t_0 from a certain time? I don’t see what is the contradiction here exactly.

Comment: @Brenda 1) Do you understand what was going on *before* the last paragraph? 2) Of course, not: for every time $t$, there are values of $\xi_0$ and $\xi_\sigma$ for which $t_0=t_\sigma=t$. The story is that the conjecture is equivalent to $\frac{s+\sigma}s F(x,y)>1$ all the way, which is incompatible with $F(x,y)\to 0$ as $x\to 1$. 3) Do you want do switch to the chat room?

Comment: Now I see the relation between that line and the original conjecture and now makes sense to have this analysis…. I guess what I don’t understand are the sub-conclusions on the way like the (1-x)^p part but maybe I should try to simulate those to see it properly

Comment: I guess at some point I believed the claim to be false as it was impossible to prove it no matter what I tried. But this approach is so neat and elegant. Very nice!